# 12.04 system (authenticate password)

Tags: 12.04

made a new user account and made it administrative but forgot to make a password and want to install some apps and it is asking to authenticate and in the accounts information the password is disable

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu use the original account (the one you create when installing Ubuntu) as root password. You can use it to authenticate yourself when installing a new package.

If your new user account is an administrator account, Ubuntu will use this user password as sudo password for this user account. You can use it to authenticate yourself too.

Comment: it is not working